# How to break row inside a Bootstrap table?

Tags: javascript, arrays, twitter-bootstrap, vue.js

I'm trying to make a `.join()` on an array that is inside a table. The expected result is that each car (in the example below) is on one row.

I've tried using `.join("\r\n")` and `.join("<br />")`, but it doesn't work. What am I missing?

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#table",
  data() {
    return {
      items: [
        { firstname: "John", lastname: "Doe", cars: ["Ferrari", "Tesla"] },
        { firstname: "Jane", lastname: "Doe", cars: ["BMW", "Civic"] },
        { firstname: "Jack", lastname: "Doo", cars: ["Corsa", "Golf"] },
        { firstname: "Julie", lastname: "Doo", cars: ["Fiesta", "Brasilia"] }
      ],
      fields: [
        { key: "firstname", label: "First name" },
        { key: "lastname", label: "Last name" },
        { key: "cars", label: "Cars" }
      ]
    };
  },
  methods: {
    join() {
      for (let item of this.items) {
        item.cars = item.cars.join("<br />")
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.11/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@latest/dist/bootstrap-vue.js"></script>

<div id="table">
  <b-button @click="join">Join Array</b-button>
  <b-table :fields="fields" :items="items" />
</div>
```

Same snippet above but on [CodePen](https://codepen.io/arnonrdp/pen/gOGBbOR?editors=1011).

Comment: Perhaps you need to re-render?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue you are seeing is that the content is not being interpreted so it appears as text. To adjust for this, use the [`cell(key)`](https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/table#comp-ref-b-table-slots) slot. Then within the slot, use [`v-html`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Raw-HTML) to interpret the string as html.

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#table",
  data() {
    return {
      items: [
        { firstname: "John", lastname: "Doe", cars: ["Ferrari", "Tesla"] },
        { firstname: "Jane", lastname: "Doe", cars: ["BMW", "Civic"] },
        { firstname: "Jack", lastname: "Doo", cars: ["Corsa", "Golf"] },
        { firstname: "Julie", lastname: "Doo", cars: ["Fiesta", "Brasilia"] }
      ],
      fields: [
        { key: "firstname", label: "First name" },
        { key: "lastname", label: "Last name" },
        { key: "cars", label: "Cars" }
      ]
    };
  },
  methods: {
    join() {
      for (let item of this.items) {
        item.cars = item.cars.join("<br />")
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.11/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@latest/dist/bootstrap-vue.js"></script>

<div id="table">
  <b-button @click="join">Join Array</b-button>
  <b-table :fields="fields" :items="items">
      <template #cell(cars)="data">
        <span v-html="data.value"></span>
      </template>
  </b-table>
</div>
```

Comment: I would generally advise against using v-html, as it opens up your site to [XSS vulnerabilities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting). So if users have the ability to edit these `cars` strings, I would be careful about using it.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want it to always be on a separate line (and not only after clicking the button in your example), then you can use the slots that `<b-table>` provides to customize the content of the column, and use a simple `v-for` to render each element in it's own `<div>`.

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#table",
  data() {
    return {
      items: [
        { firstname: "John", lastname: "Doe", cars: ["Ferrari", "Tesla"] },
        { firstname: "Jane", lastname: "Doe", cars: ["BMW", "Civic"] },
        { firstname: "Jack", lastname: "Doo", cars: ["Corsa", "Golf"] },
        { firstname: "Julie", lastname: "Doo", cars: ["Fiesta", "Brasilia"] }
      ],
      fields: [
        { key: "firstname", label: "First name" },
        { key: "lastname", label: "Last name" },
        { key: "cars", label: "Cars" }
      ]
    };
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.12/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.21.2/dist/bootstrap-vue.js"></script>

<div id="table">
  <b-table :fields="fields" :items="items">
    <template #cell(cars)="{ value }">
      <div v-for="car in value" :key="car">
        {{ car }}
      </div>
    </template>
  </b-table>
</div>
```

Comment: In fact, I was already using `<b-table>` slots. The problem is: this way, the data is not sent to the table with separate lines. This hinders, for example, exporting the table or reusing it since everything I need to do will require me to re-format the columns that have arrays. I'm trying to reuse the code.

Comment: Not really sure I understand the problem you're describing. But it's probably worth adding to the question so people know the full picture of what you're doing.